# What tool or method will create concentrated dots in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

I need a thick spray of dots. I have tried both the Symbol spray tool and the paint brush to create a spray effect but a tight one. I'm not looking for scatter so much as a "pile-on" effect. Neither tool really works because with the symbol sprayer the dots seem to avoid each other and spread instead of thickening and with the paint brush it only does one line at a time.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

Symbols should work.

Double click the **Symbol Sprayer Tool** and adjust the **Intensity** and **Symbol Set Density** options to create the "pile on" aspect.

[image: Symbolism]

Then it's merely a matter of holding the mouse down.

[image: spray]

You can then use the **Symbol Scruncher Tool** to increase the density further if you need.

Comment: for some reason my intensity and density counter stops at 10. I can't go past that...

Comment: @deecemobile my screenshot is a bit deceiving, 10 is the maximum. If I hit the OK button in that screenshot the "30" becomes "10". The animation is using 10 for each setting.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if this will work. I'll play around with it more. It's for shading for post-print (1 color) so the dots have to give the idea of a shade of that color.

Comment: So you're looking for a "stipple" effect? That may require something entirely different. A scatter brush would probably be best for that.

Comment: I'm in love with that GIF